# Automating menu bar click movement using Test complete

Tags: c#, windows, ui-automation, testcomplete

I am new to Windows app automation and test complete. I am trying to automate the menu bar click movement. But the test complete spy could not find it. How to automate such scenario. Like the menubar has File, View, Tool etc option. My use case is to click on Tool and select any of the dropdown value.

My use case is to click on Tool and select any of the dropdown value from menubar.

Comment: Are you able to locate the menu bar items `(File, View, Tool)` in the Spy tool?

Comment: No , ia m not. The entire screen structure is coming. The spy could not identify the menu bar

Comment: If you have no way of spying the menu bar items, possible you can spy the menu bar itself? If so, you can use it's x,y coordinates and move the mouse pointer z number of pixels +x across the menu bar and cause a click to open the drop down menu, then in my experience, you typically can spy the drop down. Good luck,

Answer (score 0):

For Desktop License of TestComplete there is 
'Text Recognition' feature which will get TextObject items from specified object.
To Enable follow steps as below
On Project Properties 
Select Open Applications | Text Recognition
On Tab 'Accepted windows' add class name of your screen object.
Save project and refresh Object heirarchy you will be able to see TextObject("File") etc